# Composer, why do I have multiple subdirectories?

Tags: composer-php

I'm new to composer. I've installed one package with several dependecies. I get a strange directory structure inside the vendor folder:

```
/vendor
    /symphony
        /event-dispatcher
            /Symphony
                /Component
                    /EventDispatcher
        /http-foundation
            /Symphony
                /Component
                    /HttpFoundation
        /...
            /Symphony
                /Component
```

I would expect to have all symphony components in one folder `/Symphony/Component`, but instead of this, I have as many `/Symphony/Component` as I have symphony components.

I have a very basic composer.json file:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Mb\\": "inc/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/Ratchet": "0.3.*",
        "react/zmq": "0.2.*"
    }
}
```

Is this the normal behavior, or did I do something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This directory structure is normal. The `cboden/ratchet` package requires the `symfony/http-foundation` and `symfony/routing` packages. Those in turn have additional dev dependencies including more Symfony packages. Composer installs each composer package independently into its own directory in `vendor`. The package source code is inside each one of those. Because all the Symfony packages use the same root namespace, you end up with a lot of packages with similar directory structures. This is how composer is designed.